# Django ORM values_list with '__in' filter performance

Tags: python, django, performance

What is the preferred way to filter query set with '__in' in Django?

```
providers = Provider.objects.filter(age__gt=10)
consumers = Consumer.objects.filter(consumer__in=providers)
```

or

```
providers_ids = Provider.objects.filter(age__gt=10).values_list('id', flat=True)
consumers = Consumer.objects.filter(consumer__in=providers_ids)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These should be totally equivalent. Underneath the hood Django will optimize both of these to a subselect query in SQL. See the [QuerySet API reference on `in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

This queryset will be evaluated as subselect statement:

```
SELECT ... WHERE consumer.id IN (SELECT id FROM ... WHERE _ IN _)
```

However you can force a lookup based on passing in explicit values for the primary keys by calling `list` on your `values_list`, like so:

```
providers_ids = list(Provider.objects.filter(age__gt=10).values_list('id', flat=True))
consumers = Consumer.objects.filter(consumer__in=providers_ids)
```

This could be more performant in some cases, for example, when you have few providers, but it will be totally dependent on what your data is like and what database you're using. See the "Performance Considerations" note in the link above.

Answer (score 6):

I Agree with Wilduck. However couple of notes

You can combine a filter such as these into one like this:

```
consumers = Consumer.objects.filter(consumer__age__gt=10)
```

This would give you the same result set - in a single query.

The second thing, to analyze the generated query, you can use the `.query` clause at the end.

Example:

```
print Provider.objects.filter(age__gt=10).query
```

would print the query the ORM would be generating to fetch the resultset.